# How to separate a dataframe according to column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe called raw and it looks like the following:

[image]

I'm trying to separate the main data frame into two separate data frames (ex. df1 and df2) based on whether BDA is null or not. How can I do this while preserving the other rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe `df`, you can use simple slicing:

```
df1 = df[df['BDA'] = 'null']
df2 = df[df['BDA'] = 'not null']
```

This will not affect your original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `groupby`

```
df1,df2=[x for _,x in df.groupby('BDA')]
```